# how to find the limits of all data types in c

Tags: c, types

We all know that all the data types which we used in c has fix limit like

```
char range from -128 to 127
integer store value from -2147483648 to 2147483647
```

Like this all have fix limits.

My question is very simple that if we use  header file we can easily find out the range of all data types. But is there any process or logic through which we can find limits of all these data types without using Any predefined function or header files or Macros??

If any please solved out my query

and I also want to know about  header file. Is there any method to vary the number of digit after decimal in float ??

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like `limits.h`

Comment: sizeof(char) = 1 * 8 = 8 (bits) --> 2^8 = 268 --> limits: -1 * 256 / 2  = -128 and 256 / 2 - 1 = 127. Is that what you mean?

Comment: check the limits.h header file

Comment: @WhozCraig: He mentioned "without using header files"

Comment: @ vad can you show your code ??

Comment: don't use that header files where all these data types ranged has pre defined. 

You use your header file but in <limits.h> header files has given all the data types limits you have to only type that header file and it will give you direct resule but i dont want that

Comment: You don't want to do that because... ? The representation and the limits therein are implementation defined and constrained by rules of the standard. Not coincidentally said-implementation is required to provide a likewise-standard-mandated representation for exposing those limits. `limits.h` is there for this reason. Is there any particular reason *outside* of sheer curiosity you would *not* want to use what is provided by standard-mandate to facilitate the very limits you seek to acquire? Just curious (sheerly, at that).

Comment: @WhozCraig  we find out the range of these non-integer types using sizeof operator???

Comment: No. you find them out by using the very macros you seek to avoid. If floating point is your bag of hammers, using `float.h`. Everything else you seek should (better) be in `limits.h`. If it isn't, there likely is no platform-independent way of acquiring it.

Answer (score 1):

The header files are there for a reason, for signed integer types the admissible range depends on properties of the types that are otherwise not observable. (For unsigned types it is simple, BTW, the minimum is always `0` and the maximum the converted value of `-1`).

A signed type depends on

- the width of the type, that is its size in bytes times the number of bits in the type, `CHAR_BIT`
- the eventual presence of padding bits
- the sign representation of the type, since they may realize different minimal values for the type

Comment: what about the digit after the decimal in float. I know we have to use <float.h> header file. But is there any other method to  vary the size of digit after decimal in floats

Comment: Floating point types are even more complicated, since they may have a lot of properties (infinities, negative zeros, ...) and there are several macros and functions in the standard that address these properties. There is no way of observing them directly without these macros.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to C but I noticed that if you decrement an unsigned type it will be assigned the maximum value.

I've included `limits.h` just to compare the results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{   
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned short s;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned long l;

    // char
    printf("UCHAR_MAX  = %u\n",  UCHAR_MAX);
    printf("UCHAR_MAX  = %u\n", --c);

    // short
    printf("USHRT_MAX  = %u\n",  USHRT_MAX);
    printf("USHRT_MAX  = %u\n",  --s);

    // int
    printf("UINT_MAX   = %u\n",  UINT_MAX);
    printf("UINT_MAX   = %u\n",  --i);

    // long
    printf("ULONG_MAX  = %lu\n",  ULONG_MAX);
    printf("ULONG_MAX  = %lu\n",  --l);
}
```

And the results:

```
UCHAR_MAX  = 255
UCHAR_MAX  = 255
USHRT_MAX  = 65535
USHRT_MAX  = 65535
UINT_MAX   = 4294967295
UINT_MAX   = 4294967295
ULONG_MAX  = 18446744073709551615
ULONG_MAX  = 140731079060271
```

As you can see it works for all except long, as to why.. well maybe someone more experienced than me can explain.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is warranted.

Consider the second assertion it the question:

```
integer store value from -2147483648 to 2147483647
```

This is true only on a 32-bit system.  On a 16-bit system an integer may store a value in the -32768 to 32767 range.

As you indicate in the question, most programmers rely on header files such as limit.h to determine ranges of data types.

One way to calculate integer limits is to use 'sizeof({the type}) x 8' to determine how many bits are available.  Then, of course, subtract one bit for 'signed' integer types allowing for the 2's complement sign bit.

While such a method may work well integers; it is marginal with non-integer types, such as float/double, etc.

Comment: Is it applicable to all the data types ?

Comment: and if I want to find out the value after decimal in float then how will i find out it suppose that f=12.345678 .It's predefined six points after decimal so how we calculate it that it's only has 6 digit range after decimal.Is there any other way to find out it

Comment: @user3591571, it is of marginal value with non-integer types, such as float/double.  However, knowing the structure of these types in detail, one could devise a method for determining the limits of these as well.

Comment: Moriancumercan we find out the range of these non-integer types using sizeof operator???

Comment: @user3591571, unfortunately no.  The sizeof() such types alone is little more than a hint; however, such a hint could be used to determine the limits -if- the internal structure of these types is properly understood.

Comment: can you give me little more explain about it. I didn't get you.

Answer (score -1):

The range of a data type depends on how many bits it has.

For example, char is stored on 1 byte (= 8 bits), which gives the range (-2^7) - (2^7-1).

So the formula for signed data types is:

```
2^(((sizeof(t)-1) * 8) to 2^((sizeof(t)-1) * 8) - 1.
```

For unsigned data types it's:

```
0 to 2^((sizeof(t)) * 8) - 1.
```

Where t is the data type.
It's multiplied by 8, cause sizeof returns size in bytes.

This formula doesn't apply to floating point types since they're stored differently. You could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610999/how-to-calculate-double-float-precision) or [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) to have a better understanding on that. I was never in the need to work with numbers nearing the limit AND make it run cross-platform, so the limit was always a constant value for me.

Comment: That's assuming 2's complement and no padding , and `CHAR_BIT` gives the number of bits per byte. Also this doesn't cover floating point types.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the result of this would momentarily be with `float`, `double`, etc., which I assume are included in "all the data types" (that that does seem a little overt to request).

Comment: and if I want to find out the value after decimal in float then how will i find out it suppose that f=12.345678 .It's predefined six points after decimal so how we calculate it that it's only has 6 digit range after decimal.Is there any other way to find out it

Comment: Depending on precision (p), you can multiply f by 10^p.

Comment: that means you want to say that we can vary the size of digit after decimal more than 6 and less than 6 ???