# How to find max value of float, double, long double

Tags: c

I am a newbie in C and in programming in general. I have to come up with some kind of algorithms that find size of type, its max and min value. The catch is that i can use only those libraries that are given in code (standard stdio.h, math.h and conio.h). I came up with an idea to use overflow in C. Example:

```
{
unsigned char c = -1;
for (c; c < 0; c--);
printf("%d\n", c);
unsigned short s = -1;
for (s; s < 0; s--);
printf("%d\n", s);
int i = -1;
while (i < 0) {
    i = i - 1024;
}
printf("%d\n", i);
long l = -1;
while (l < 0)
{
    l = l - 1024;
}
printf("%d\n", l);
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

So this code finds max value of unsigned types. But I have difficulties with finding values of float, double and long double.

Comment: Decide for a language. There are different answers for either. See [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Comment: Here's the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) you want then. Just use that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find the limits of all data types in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465134/how-to-find-the-limits-of-all-data-types-in-c)

Comment: What *are* you allowed to use?  Anything other than arithmetic, such as maybe the `ldexp()` and `frexp()` families of functions?  And what assumptions are you permitted to make?  C has much looser constraints on floating-point representation than on integer representation, and pretty lax requirements for FP behavior.

Comment: The header `<float.h>` contains the information you're looking for.  Or is `<float.h>` one of the 'sizeof or `<limits.h>` and these kinds of tricks'?

Comment: "... and these kinds of tricks" - `sizeof` and `limits.h` are the standard and correct way. **Anything else** is the "trick"

Comment: The first two loops never execute; the tested condition is false before the first iteration so the body of the loop (which is empty) and the decrement is never executed.  It isn't really clear why you switched to `while` loops for the last two — consistency is good.  The second pair of loops use undefined behaviour (signed integer 'overflow') to spot when a problem has happened.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code has several problems, but that seems not to be what you are actually asking about.  The actual question is about limits for the real types:

> i have difficulties with finding values of float, double and long double.

That is indeed tricky if you must do it without relying on the standard library's built-in facilities for that purpose (mostly various macros defined by `float.h`).  In fact, you cannot portably do it at all with arithmetic alone, because the standard specifies:

> If  an *exceptional  condition* occurs  during  the  evaluation  of  an  expression  (that  is,  if  the result  is  not  mathematically  defined  ***or  not  in  the  range  of  representable  values  for  its type***), the behavior is undefined.

(C2011, 6.5/5; emphasis added)

The only ways to probe the limit via arithmetic would involve discovering operations whose results are out of range, but you cannot portably recognize those because there cannot be any reliable way to recognize undefined behavior (for then the behavior would be defined).

If you cannot use `float.h` then you can still determine the limiting FP values if

- you assume that the real types use an IEEE-754-like representation with sign, binary exponent with unknown size and bias, and binary mantissa with unknown size;
- you assume that type `uintmax_t` has more value bits than any of the real types of interest have mantissa bits;
- you assume that the number of mantissa bits in each real type is not greater than the corresponding maximum exponent plus one; and
- you are able to rely on math function `ldexp` (/ `ldexpf` / `ldexpl`), which has defined behavior when asked to compute a value that would be out of range.

If those are acceptable conditions then read on ....

### Determining FP mantissa size

You can determine the number of bits of mantissa by performing round-trip conversions from `uintmax_t` to <fp type> to `uintmax_t` with values having various numbers of significant bits (and no trailing zeroes).  The largest number of significant bits that can survive the round trip unchanged is the number of bits in the mantissa of the FP type under test.

### Determining FP exponent range

You can determine the exponent range of `double` (for example) by calling `ldexp()` with `1.0` for the first argument and various values for the second.  The largest exponent value that does not cause a range error to occur is the maximum radix-2 exponent.  The smallest (most negative) value that does not cause a range error is the one greater than the minimum exponent minus the number of bits of mantissa.  You can do the same with the other real types, using the appropriate type-specific functions from the `ldexp` family.

### Computing the limiting values

Given the mantissa size `mbits` and exponent limits `exp_max` and `exp_min` for a real type, you can compute the limiting values like so:

- maximum value: construct a `uintmax_t` value `v` having its `mbits` lowest-order bits set to 1, and all its higher-order bits set to 0.  Compute the maximum as `ldexp(v, 1 + exp_max - mbits)`.  *Think about why the second argument is `1 + exp_max - mbits` rather than simply `exp_max`.*
- minimum (positive) normalized value: compute the value as `ldexp(1, exp_min)`.  *Think about why the first argument is 1 (or 1.0) rather than `v`, and why the computation is not ...*
- minimum (positive) subnormal value: compute the value as `ldexp(1, 1 + exp_min - mbits)`. *Think about why the second argument is `1 + exp_min - mbits`.  What value would necessarily result if `exp_min - mbits` were used instead?*

### General considerations

To ensure that the compiler (if it conforms) does not trip you up with any kind of laxness or optimization of your conversions, you may want to write to a `volatile` variable of the appropriate real type, and then read back the value of that variable.  For example,

```
uintmax_t probe = < some computation >;
volatile double converted = probe;
_Bool is_equal = (probe == (uintmax_t) converted);
```

Also, the procedure above depends in part on being able to recognize when `ldexp()` reports a range error.  This is in itself a bit tricky to do portably, but that's a whole other question.