# C# float variable showing epsilon number

Tags: c#

i am facing a problem while assigning a large value to a float variable. Following is the code

```
float f1=99999999999.959f;
```

When i am retrieving value from this variable it is showing **1.0E+11**  value. i want to get my original value. Can anyone help me to sort-out this problem.

Comment: Don't worry, your original value is more or less still there, you just need to represent it as you want...

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Comment: Check this page that explains all the different string representation of numerics :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Adriano, I am populating a custom list from database and binding this to combobox. This custom list contains a property “Account”. When I am getting selected value from this. It is showing me the value 1.0E+11. I want to retrieve the original value. Can you tel me how I get my original value.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, float values only have a precision of 7 digits, so you're getting the best you can out of that data type. If you need more precision, use double or decimal.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you are getting back the number you entered, to the degree of accuracy available from a float (about 6-7 d.p.)

So firstly, the storage of the value has limited precision, and secondly the way you display it may add further rounding.

If you use a double, you will increase the precision to around 15 d.p., or you can go further and use a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

**Primitives** types **float** and **double** are **approximations**.

Here is a great response on their precision: [How to Calculate Double + Float Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610999/how-to-calculate-double-float-precision)

Even **decimal** has this problem. C# does not come with **big num** class, but you can use libraries for that. If you need more accurate decimal numbers then **decimal** (±1.0 × 10^−28 to ±7.9 × 10^28) you should try them.

Example: https://bcl.codeplex.com/ (BigRational)