# Error when calculating max value for double variable in C

Tags: c, debugging, double, limits

I followed the solution here: [How to Calculate Double + Float Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610999/how-to-calculate-double-float-precision) and have been unable to calculate the maximum value for variables of type double.

I run:

```
double dbl_max = pow(2, pow(2, 10)) * (1-pow(2, -53));
printf("%.2e", dbl_max);

Result: inf
```

Or:

```
 double dbl_max = (pow(2, pow(2, 10)));
 printf("%.2e", dbl_max);

Result: inf
```

Or:

```
double dbl_max = pow(2, pow(2, 9)) * (1-pow(2, -53));
printf("%.2e", dbl_max);

Result: 1.34e+154
```

Why isn't the calculation fitting into the variable? The top sample above works just fine for float variables.

Comment: The intermediate exponent is one too high.  Change `pow(2, 10)` to `(pow(2, 10) - 1)` and it should work.  You can compensate by multiplying the final result by 2.

Comment: Do not use `pow` to calculate powers of 2. A good math library will get these right, but not all math libraries will—`pow` is a floating-point function, and math libraries of mediocre quality will return approximate results. To produce an integer power of two in floating-point, use `ldexp(1, n)` for `double` or `ldexpf(1, n)` for `float`, where `n` is an integer. To produce a power of two in integer, use `(type) 1 << n`, where “type” is the integer type you want for the result, such as `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The intermediate exponent is one too high. 
>   Change `pow(2, 10)` to `(pow(2, 10) - 1)` and it
>   should work.  You can compensate by multiplying the final result by
>   2.
>                       – Tom Karzes

```
double dbl_max = pow(2, pow(2, 10)-1) * (1-pow(2, -53)) * 2;
printf("%.2e", dbl_max);
```

Comment: Thank you Elad. Why is the intermediate exponent too high? I would think the calculation should fit exactly into the variable. Is it related to what Eric said about inferior math libraries returning approximate results?