# Is there a function to find out how to get precise numbers represented in float format?

Tags: python

ok, 2^32, 2^32+1, 2^32+2 isn't precise when stored as a float. however, 2^64 is, is there function out that i can feed it a number, and it tell me if a float will store it precisely. the only reason i am interested in floats is because i want to store very long digit numbers in as few bytes as possible. 2^64 is 20 digits. i found this article, but i'm not sure if it applies since it talks about doubles and i know python does things differently?
[How to Calculate Double + Float Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610999/how-to-calculate-double-float-precision)

Comment: If you want to store integers with lots of digits precisely, use ints. floats won't help.

Comment: Also, what the heck is up with your indentation?

Comment: well if u can store 10+ digits in 32bits, let me know what type you use?

Comment: What you're hoping for is probably information-theoretically impossible. We would need more context to know for sure.

Comment: 2^32 is precise.

Answer (score 0):

This is complex topic. Not only float/double may not be good at representing specific value, computations can add their own error. There is whole branch of mathematics that tries to study this problem.

Solution generally is to use integers. If integers are too small in given language there is always option for software emulated integers of any length.

There are solid libraries for Python that support just that.